# Cannot connect to internet in Kali Linux

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, kali-linux

I have installed Kali linux in dual boot with my windows. At the time of installation I received an error that says:- “DHCP failed to auto-configure”. So I selected to install it manually and move up with my installation ,& successfully installed the OS. Now, when I tried to connect to internet from my MTS dongle, it doesn’t show any setup or drive that can let me install the MTS drivers in my OS. Just to confirm if my internet is working or not, I have tried to ping to 8.8.8.8 but received an error saying:- “Network is unreachable” What I’ve tried:

I tried to configure my client to use a DHCP server on a network interface(“eth0”) by bringing down the network interface & going to etc/network/interfaces and replacing:- auto eth0 iface eth0 inet static by: auto eth0 iface eth0 inet dhcp and bring the network interface up. Also, I have tried to write additional information in the same file as: auto eth0 iface eth0 inet static address 192.168.1.25 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 192.168.1.1

I tried to obtain an IP address from the DHCP service from eth0 by writing following code in commandline:- root@kali ~$ dhclient eth0 it takes a while after this command, but ultimately nothing happens.

I am really in need of help so that I can install wireless card drivers. your help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.